# $v' = 1 - v^2$ ODE Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My attempt at a solution involved separating both sides and eventually arriving at $v = tanh(t+c_1)$, which further evaluates to $v = \frac{e^{t+c}-e^{-t-c}}{e^{t+c}+e^{-t-c}}$, but WolframAlpha gives a different answer.

Comment: Multiplying top and bottom by $e^{t-c}$ results in an equivalent answer, I think. Check it carefully, I did this computation quick-and-dirty.

Comment: What does WA say? So no one has to go check

Comment: Write down the definition of hyperbolic tangent and check they are equivalent, alternatively show both solutions satisfy the ODE and thus by existence and uniqueness must be the same functions.

Comment: WA gives $\frac{e^{2t}-e^{2c}}{e^{2t}+e^{2c}}$

Comment: Multiplying top and bottom of your version results in $\frac{e^{2t}-e^{-2c}}{e^{2t}+e^{-2c}}$ which is equivalent to WA's version after identifying $c \Leftrightarrow -c$.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I overlooked this equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct $$v = \frac {e^{t+c}-e^{-t-c}}{e^{t+c}+e^{-t-c}}$$

Wolfram Alpha's solution is also correct. It is the constant and multiplication by $e^t$ which makes them look different.

Depending on how you represent your constant the solution changes its form but it is the same solution.

In WA's solution you have $e^2c$ which is just a constant but different from your constant.
To avoid these kind of confusion it is best if you give your answer in terms of some initial condition.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing some other solutions. The ones with $\tanh t$ and its translates are those where $-1 <v < 1$

Another solution is $v = -1$  Another still is $v = 1.$

The final ones look the same as far as formula. One type is $\frac{1}{\tanh t}$ for $t > 0$ only. There is an asymptote along the positive part of the $y$ axis. The ODE is autonomous, you may also translate.

The last is $\frac{1}{\tanh t}$ for $t < 0$ only. There is an asymptote along the negative part of the $y$ axis.